# vuejs multiple filtered in search

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to search with vue js, normal search works fine, but if we consider that there are 1000 records in the list, and when the user wants to search by filtering, what kind of action can I apply? I couldn't understand if there is a plugin for this, I searched and couldn't find it.
I have drawn such a way, thinking that for example, users with "status blocked" and "close" want to be listed in the filtering, and if they want to search from the incoming list accordingly, I have drawn such a way, but as I said, I am new to vuejs and if you can show it as an example. Thank you from now.

[image]

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        search: '',
        userList: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Prem",
                age: 18,
                status: "close",
                gender: "male",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Chandu",
                status: "close",
                age: 20,
                gender: "female",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Shravya",
                status: "open",
                age: 35,
                gender: "female",
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "Shravya",
                status: "blocked",
                age: 35,
                gender: "female",
            }
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        filteredAndSorted() {
            function compare(a, b) {
                if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
                if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
                return 0;
            }

            return this.userList.filter(user => {
                return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            }).sort(compare)
        }
    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function (e) {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Filtered
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Name</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Age</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Gender</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Status <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="close">
                    <button>Close</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="open">
                    <button>Open</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="blocked">
                    <button>Blocked</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.."/>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="user in filteredAndSorted">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made you a snippet, take a look (no need for jquery):

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        search: '',
        selected: 'name',
        choice: '',
        choicesArr: [],
        options: [
          { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
          { text: 'Age', value: 'age' },
          { text: 'Gender', value: 'gender' },
          { text: 'Status', value: 'status' }
        ],
        userList: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Prem",
                age: 18,
                status: "close",
                gender: "male",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Chandu",
                status: "close",
                age: 20,
                gender: "female",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Shravya",
                status: "open",
                age: 35,
                gender: "female",
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "Shravya",
                status: "blocked",
                age: 35,
                gender: "female",
            }
        ]
    },
    computed: {
      filteredAndSorted() {
        function compare(a, b) {
          if (a[this.selected] < b[this.selected]) return -1;
          if (a[this.selected] > b[this.selected]) return 1;
          return 0;
        }
        return this.userList.filter(user => {
          if (this.selected === "age") {
            if(this.choicesArr.length) {
              return this.choicesArr.indexOf(user[this.selected]) >= 0
            } else {
              return !this.search || user[this.selected] === Number(this.search)
            }
          } else {
            if(this.choicesArr.length) {
              return this.choicesArr.indexOf(user[this.selected]) >= 0
            } else {
              return user[this.selected].toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            }
          }
        }).sort(compare)
      },
      choices: function() {
        return [...new Set(this.userList.map(user => user[this.selected]))];
      }  
    },
    methods: {
      addChoice() {
        this.choicesArr.push(this.choice)
        console.log(this.choicesArr)
      },
      reset() {
        this.choice = ""
        this.choicesArr = []
      }
    }
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected" >
    <option value="" disabled>Select option</option>
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value" >
      {{ option.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <select v-model="choicesArr" multiple>
    <option v-for="option in choices" v-bind:value="option" @click="addChoice">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <button @click="reset">Clear filters</button>
  <div class="search-wrapper">
      <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.."/>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="user in filteredAndSorted">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: For me to accept your answer, there is missing information, so if you are aware that I asked for multiple,
I uploaded the image I wanted.

Comment: Sir, I'm tiring you, but what I said is available in the image that will be in multiple selection :s

Comment: 2nd select option; "checkbox multiple"  olmasını istiyorum. örneğin:
status> select block+ close

Comment: 2nd select option; I want it to be "checkbox multiple". eg: status> select block close

Comment: Try now pls . In order to select more then one option you need to hold `shift` or `ctrl`

Comment: Mate, take a look at my snippet , everything works